# Application freeze when trying to change image drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm building a location-based application that uses the image of the camera instead of a 2D map as its user interfaces.

In that view, I want to draw a drawable image. When the distance between point changes, the image drawable changes too.

Everything works fine, but only at the first one.
When the image should be changed, then the application hangs.
But the image captured by the camera is still the normal way.

This is my code at `onCreate` to initialize the drawable:

```
arrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.arah);
arrow.setVisibility(0);

res =  getResources();
lurus = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.arahlurus);
kanan = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.arahkanan);
kiri = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.arahkiri);
putar = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.arahputar);
```

This is my code at method onLocationChanged():

```
arrow.setVisibility(0);
Location pointLocation = TEMP_LOCATION.get(check);
float distance = location.distanceTo(pointLocation);
int dist = (int)Math.round(distance);
//stepNext.setText("" + distance + " Meter");
//String chek = TEMP_POINT.get(check).toString();;
if (dist / 4 == 0){
    stepNext.setText("" + dist + "meter");
    Toast.makeText(ARrazerNav.this, "Jarak Dengan Checkpoint: " +dist, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else if (dist < 15){
    arrow.setVisibility(0);
    //speakWords(TEMP_NAME.get(check).toString());
    check++;
}
else if (dist >= 10 && dist <= 27){
    arrow.setVisibility(1);
    if(checkOrientation == 1){
        if (TEMP_POINT.get(check) == 1){
            arrow.setImageDrawable(lurus);
        }
        else if (TEMP_POINT.get(check) == 2){
            arrow.setImageDrawable(kanan);
        }
        else if(TEMP_POINT.get(check) == 3){
            arrow.setImageDrawable(putar);
        }
        else{
            arrow.setImageDrawable(kiri);
        }
    }else{
        if (TEMP_POINT.get(check) == 1){
            arrow.setImageDrawable(kiri);
        }
        else if (TEMP_POINT.get(check) == 2){
            arrow.setImageDrawable(lurus);
        }
        else if(TEMP_POINT.get(check) == 3){
            arrow.setImageDrawable(kanan);
        }
        else{
            arrow.setImageDrawable(putar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is solved.. please answer it yourself and accept .. otherwise post the logs from logcat when app is hanged